# PHP: IF statement vs. JS style expression

Tags: php

In situations when we need to write something like this:

```
if ($doStuff) {
    $obj->doStuff();
}
```

is it acceptable to write something like this?

```
$doStuff && $obj->doStuff();
```

If not, why?

Comment: Subjective. Try to write code that's less clever and more readable. Think of reading code like reading a book. Most people would rather read code written like a children's book than a technical novel.

Comment: Also, ask yourself why and when you would use this in JS.

Comment: I use it for initializing variables (array keys) and sometimes for simple and repetitive logic (string appending with many conditionals). I would avoid it for domain logic though - `if`s require attention. Also I like it to be different from standard boolean operations, so I use `and`/`or` operators (visible in IDE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, it's not good practice.

First, it hides the logic. Everyone can easily see what the if-construction means. The other is just... "clever" coding, which you shouldn't do.

You can't reorder the two things, although generally, you should be able to (oh wait, there are side effects!).

The result of the expression is not used? Hmm... I might just delete that line of code.

Also, I don't think doing boolean operations with parameters that are maybe void/null/... is a good thing.